# Binding ds.js Scatter Chart to JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, nvd3.js

Is it possible to create a scatter chart in ds.js by binding JSON data? The examples on the ds website use TSV files and CSV files which I could create, but would prefer to bind to data returned as a list of objects from the server. I have seen examples of other d3 controls that bind to JSON formatted data but I can not figure out how transfer that functionality onto the scatter chart.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. If you provide a specific scatter chart that you are looking at, we can provide more pointed responses.

Comment: It's the scatter plot chart - http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887118 - any tips would be very handy.

Answer (score 0):

So, to quickly modify the example at bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887118

In the index.html file, comment out or remove:

```
d3.tsv("data.tsv", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.sepalLength = +d.sepalLength;
    d.sepalWidth = +d.sepalWidth;
  });
```

as well as the concluding

```
});
```

at the very end of the file.

Add, prior to the d3.tsv call:

```
data = [
    { sepalLength:4.4, sepalWidth:3.5, petalLength:1.4, species: "setosa"},
    { sepalLength:4.9, sepalWidth:3.0, petalLength:1.3, species: "setosa"},
    { sepalLength:4.5, sepalWidth:3.0, petalLength:1.7, species: "setosa"},
    { sepalLength:4.2, sepalWidth:3.1, petalLength:1.5, species: "virginica"},
 ];
```

Done.

Now, you'll probably want to be fetching data from the server, so you simply use the [d3 json](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#wiki-d3_json) call, instead of either static data or the d3.tsv call.

Comment: Do you know If I'm able to bind the chart to a knockout observable collection?